# Boto3 how to attach public IP addresses to network interface

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm creating instances using Boto3's `create_instances()` function.

According to the AWS Instances page, some network interfaces support up to fifty IPv4 addresses.

I would like to have multiple network interfaces, each with multiple public IP addresses.

1. Do I need to attach the network interfaces, or do they come with the instance?
2. How do I attach the public IP addresses to each interface?

The IP address value doesn't matter/need to match anything, I just need additional public IP addresses for outgoing traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch an instance, you can choose whether or not you wish to associate the instance with existing network interfaces.

If you do, the network interfaces you specified will be assigned to the instance. 
If you don't, a new interface will be created and assigned to the instance.

If you wish to associate existing network interfaces after the instance has been launched you can use [attach_network_interface](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/attach_network_interface.html).

Whether or not the network interface has a public ip will depend on the configuration of the subnet in which it is created.

Comment: "Whether or not the network interface has a public ip will depend on the configuration of the subnet in which it is created."

Could you elaborate on this part? I presume you realise but I want to try and be stateless and create everything, rather than load/attach existing. All my instance creation is done on the fly, rather than manual configuration.

Comment: @rare77 it depends on whether subnet has the `auto assign public ip` setting on or not. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html . I don't understand what the rest of your comment means

Comment: Is this related? https://serverfault.com/questions/706560/assign-public-ip-not-elastic-ip-after-instance-launched

Comment: @rare77 yes, its related

Comment: Okay, so basically I need to create a subnet (each time I run my script?), set `auto assign public ip on`, then pass this subnet to my `create_instances()` as an argument, as per here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/subnet/create_instances.html?highlight=create_instances?

Comment: @rare77 no... you shouldn't create a new subnet each time, you just need one

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Does any of this answer+ change, if I use a bare metal instance?

Comment: And how many new network interfaces will be created, is it just one, or the maximum number the instance can accommodate?

Comment: @rare77 when you create an instance, only one network interface is created. if you want more you have to create those separately